# Execution failed for task ':processResources'

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processResources'.
>
> > Entry application.properties is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy
> > for details.

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhYb9.png)

[gradlekt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXKuw.png)

[gradlekt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQkBR.png)

Comment: Please see if this helps you https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17236

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.